# Add exceptions to web deploy 'remove additional files at destination' in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webdeploy, razor-pages

I'm trying to publish my web application (ASP.Net Core 2.2 Razor Pages) to my server. I have two folders that are created at runtime. One is the 'Uploads' folder and the other one is 'Logs'. The problem is that these folders are deleted every time that I publish my app.

I need to keep the 'delete additional files at destination' option enabled.

According to the asp.net core documentation:   [Exclude files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-2.1#exclude-files)

I added the following item groups to my csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MsDeploySkipRules Include="CustomSkipFolder">
    <ObjectName>dirPath</ObjectName>
    <AbsolutePath>Uploads</AbsolutePath>
  </MsDeploySkipRules>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <MsDeploySkipRules Include="CustomSkipFolder">
    <ObjectName>dirPath</ObjectName>
    <AbsolutePath>Logs</AbsolutePath>
  </MsDeploySkipRules>
</ItemGroup>
```

However, It is not still working. Is there any way to prevent web deploy from deleting these two folders at the destination?

Comment: Not in a position to confirm this, but have you tried putting the actual absolute path from the inetpub folder in there instead of just the folder names? The documentation you linked sets their path starting with \wwwroot\

Comment: @Logarr Thank you for your response. I'll try that & will let know the result.

Comment: Why not just add a script step and remove just the files you want removed? Then, you can turn off "delete additional files at destination" and have complete control.

Comment: @M.Sh did you ever manage to resolve this?

Comment: @ChrisPratt because some of the files required to be removed have randomly generated file names as part of the publish mechanism.